# Summation to infinity greater than $c$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Suppose $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\ell(I_n)>c$ where $\ell(I_n)\ge 0$ for all $n$.

Prove that $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\sum_{n=1}^N\ell(I_n)>c$.

Comment: What is $\ell(I_{n})$?

Comment: @JWP_HTX It doesn't matter.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo of course - I read the question too quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence
$$
s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \ell(I_k),
$$
is increasing (not necessarily strictly), and hence either it tends to infinity of it tends to a non-negative number $m$, which is if larger than $c$. If all the elements of $\{s_n\}$ where less that $c$, i.e.
$$
s_n\le c, \quad \text{for all $n\in\mathbb N$,} 
$$
then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ell(I_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} s_n\le c,
$$
which contradicts the hypothesis.

Hence, there is some $n\in\mathbb N$, such that 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\ell(I_k)=s_n>c.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Abridged solution.** If the result *were* false, the increasing sequence $\sum\limits_1^N \ell(I_n)$ would be bounded above by $c$ and so its limit. Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

Write out the definition of $\sum_{j=1}^\infty l(I_n)$.